# Why Process0 is not defined as Process[Id, O]

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

```
sealed trait Process[+F[_], +O]
/**
 * Created by pach on 11/07/14.
 */
package object stream {

  type Process0[+O] = Process[Nothing,O]
...
}
```

This is how **Process0** defined.

Actually I cannot understand why this compiles, because `Nothing` takes no type param.

To represent a stream with no effect

> why not just set the context type **F** to value type itself(using identity type constructor, `scalaz.Scalaz.Id`).

```
type Process0[+O] = Process[Id, O]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect it to compile? Being `Nothing` a subtype of all the types the compiler knows that even if you have a complex type, `Nothing` would still be a subtype.

Comment: @EndeNeu by writing `Process[+F[_], +O]`, we actually expect the `F`  has one type parameter, but `Nothing` takes no parameter, so, it is a little surprising

Comment: I would say that the compiler is smart enough to know that regardless of how a type is constructed or regardless how how many type parameters it takes, `Nothing` will always be a subtype of it, unfortunately there's nothing specific around about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala compiler treats `Nothing` a bit differently than other types, e.g the same trick won't work with `Null`, although it's a bottom type for all reference types. You can check subtype relationship using `implicits` and special method `<:<`, like this:

```
scala> implicitly[Nothing <:< List[_]]
res1: <:<[Nothing,List[_]] = <function1>
```

And if there is no relationship you'll see:

```
scala> implicitly[Null <:< Int]
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that Null <:< Int.
              implicitly[Null <:< Int]
```

As for your main question, i'm not that familiar with scalaz-streams, but as i understand type `Id` is just a type itself, i.e `type Id[A] = A`, so if you had `Process[Id, O]`, this would mean that you have some non-effectful input which gives some output. But in case of `Process0` there shouldn't be any input at all, it should only generate some output.